# Please post some tutorials links on charts4j

Tags: java, charts, google-visualization

I have to generate charts on my Web application, and after getting the answer of [Is there any free library which can be used to generate Graphs in J2EE environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639282/is-there-any-free-library-which-can-be-used-to-generate-graphs-in-j2ee-environmen), I chose [Chart4j](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/) for this purpose. The reason behind picking this API over JFreeChart is its ease of use, and also I am tempted with [chartle](http://www.chartle.net/gallery), which is using [Chart4j](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/).

The problem is, there is no or say very little matter I found on chart4j, if you have some tutorial links for this API then please post them. The best part is the [author of charts4j](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32174/julien-chastang) is here in SO :)

### Note

I would like to have clickable charts like http://www.chartle.net/gallery is having.

Comment: I don't see now what you really want. You rejected JFreeChart since Chart4J is easy to use, but you claim you now can't use it, and it doesn't (maybe) have the features of Chartle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry this took me so long to find. You two choices:

1. [Example code](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/). The gallery has code samples under each image.
2. [Javadoc](http://charts4j.googlecode.com/svn/tags/v1.2/doc/index.html). I put a lot of effort into making the javadoc, clear and complete (hopefully).

I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

These are 2 links which i found very helpful.
Please refer the example code first which julien has posted..

Suppose for a bar chart, http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/source/browse/tags/v1.2/example/com/googlecode/charts4j/BarChartExample.java#51
in this example , the method , toURLString() creates the url string that creates the bar chart for you..this generated url will look like the string 'expectedString' (in the eg)

you'll understand this url string better if you refer the following link

http://psychopyko.com/tutorial/how-to-use-google-charts/

https://developers.google.com/chart/

and of course do refer the documentation for charts4j.

and, thanks a lot julien for charts4j..:)

Comment: The links don't work anymore. :(

Answer (score 0):

Is the [gallery](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/) not of use ? Each example chart has the sample code linked below it.

(I really wouldn't discount JFreeChart though, if you're looking for examples. I could do everything I needed after checking the samples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/CatalogChart.htm))

Comment: actually none of those are clickable like http://www.chartle.net/gallery. i am expecting something like that.

Comment: No part of your question mentions 'clickable' charts.